Linux: Catching Ctrl+C breaks stdin
I'm writing a test application for a console text input library. The idea of that part of the library is to just treat any input as a regular text input, even Ctrl+[letter] combinations. And for the most part, it works rather well. But for some reason, every time I try out Ctrl+C, regular input just stops working - I can continue reading input character by character via getchar and read, but with regular stdin, I seem to be only able to press Ctrl+C again, nothing happens when I just try to type like normal. I succeed at using std::cin by just hitting the return key though.
I tested it on Ubuntu, both as WSL in the Windows Terminal and on a full Ubuntu VM.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
termios tOld, tNew;

tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &tOld);
tNew = tOld;

tNew.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN | IXON | ECHO);
tNew.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF);

tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tNew);

// further processing (reading via read and getchar and 'parsing' the input)

tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tOld);

I wonder what I'm doing wrong.
The other possible cause for this error is this code that I use for processing ESC presses:
std::function<bool(unsigned)> fnWaitForNextKey =
    [](unsigned iMillis) -> bool
    {
        struct timeval tv;
        fd_set fds;

        tv.tv_sec = 0;
        tv.tv_usec = iMillis * 1000;
        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);

        return select(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    };


You have to handle the signals

Have a look at Catch Ctrl-C in C for the signal handling.

I know about signal handling, but since I would have to remove ISIG from my mask, I assume I would have to handle multiple signals, not only the Ctrl+C one? I already tried just adding signal handling code to what I have, but it wasn't called in the given environment.

What we need is A Minimal Complete Reproducible Example. You say you tried adding signal handling code, but if we can't see what you did, it makes it impossible to help. Did you use signal or the recommended sigaction? How did you implement the signals and signal handlers? Add the MCRE at the bottom of your question (don't erase what you have so far)

i got rusty with my c++. but it looks that you return bool type from the lambda. i do not think it is right thing to do, because select function returns int. converting int to bool will produce same result for negative and positive return. is that what you expect?

@user14063792468 I know about that. If I remember correctly, I initially only added this function to make it work as intended quickly; I was of the opinion that I don't need to explicitly handle negative values. But I could be wrong, I don't have much experience with the Linux C library documentation, so rn I primarily rely on people providing solutions on sites like SO.

@DavidC.Rankin Thank you so much - a) for the hint and b) because while I created the MCRE, I noticed my mistake. It was a silly mistake, basically a Copy'n'Paste error. I'll add that do the question. Considering deleting the question altogether, as it's just a silly mistake on my part.

There's no need to edit the question to say you found a solution. Posting an answer serves that purpose.

I found my error: the 2nd call to tcsetattr (to restore the previous settings) was not always called. A silly copy-and-paste error.
For anyone interested, I have to pieces of code handling the actual input, divided via #ifdef and #elif. One is for Windows and one is for Linux. In the Windows code, I immediately return, while in the Linux code, I set a variable that I return later. But on Ctrl+[letter] combinations, I copied the return and didn't notice it was wrong 
Something like this:
#ifdef _WIN32
  const uint8_t input = _getch();

  // Ctrl + [letter] => uppercase letter + CTRL flag
  if (input >= 0x01 && input <= 0x1A)
    return input | 0x40 | FLAG_CTRL;

  // regular ASCII character
  else if (input >= 0x20 && input <= 0x7E)
    return input;

#elif __linux__

  termios tOld, tNew;

  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &tOld);
  tNew = tOld;

  tNew.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN | IXON | ECHO);
  tNew.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF);

  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tNew);


  uint8_t result;

  const uint8_t input = getchar();
  // Ctrl + [letter] => uppercase letter + CTRL flag
  if (input >= 0x01 && input <= 0x1A)
    return input | 0x40 | FLAG_CTRL; // <-- should be "result = "!

  // regular ASCII character
  else if (input >= 0x20 && input <= 0x7E)
    result = input;


  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tOld);

  return result;

#endif


This answer is not very meaningful if the code in the question doesn't have the relevant #ifdef. Show the actual original code in the question, and put the fix in the answer.

Good job. I'm glad you solved your problem. (funny how that happens sometimes when you go back over your code having a chat with the duck... see: How to debug small programs to understand the duck reference :) If you do a good write-up, I'm happy to come back by and vote for a good answer.

@Barmar The original code is extremely long, as many input 'strings' are handled (regular ASCII, Ctrl+letter, Backspace, Del, Esc, ...), both for Windows and Linux with separate switch statements. But I now added a short summary of what was wrong.

@RobinLe We don't need the full code, but a [mre] that shows what it was doing wrong.

@Barmar But that's exactly what I did now, right?

You added code to the answer, but the question still doesn't have the code with #ifdef that needed to be changed.

@Barmar I suppose my summary is easy to misunderstand? I wrote all the relevant code. My error was that I copied the line containing a return instead of result =  from the _WIN32 section into the __linux__ section.

refer to The GNU C Library, 17.4.10 Noncanonical Input
In the terminal’s c_lflag and c_iflag, probably can try to use noncanonical input, and turns off most processing to give an unmodified channel to the terminal.
tNew.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO|ECHONL|ICANON|ISIG|IEXTEN);
tNew.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK|BRKINT|PARMRK|ISTRIP|INLCR|IGNCR|ICRNL|IXON);

